# How to implement selective pinch-zooming on mobile web UI?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, mobile, touch

I would like to modify a browser-based ebook-reader interface such that the user can touch-zoom (pinch-zoom) on the content (the page of the ebook, an SVG inside a div) but without causing UI elements to also zoom (a fixed bar across the bottom and a variety of slide-in elements).

Currently the UI elements are in a `position:fixed` div at the bottom of the page, which responsively resizes so that it is always a convenient scale. The "page" we want to selectively allow zooming for is in a full-height div occupying most of the page, containing SVG. The slide-in elements are also divs with `position:absolute`

So in essence we want to allow the user to pinch-zoom (using a multi-touch screen), only on the "page" div but without causing the other divs to zoom.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

(We have implemented a slider zoom interface for desktop browsers which works fine, but is less intuitive as a mobile interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't think there's not really specific code one could give you, [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) is probably something you'll want to look into.

I'd imagine the code would look something like this by looking at their [get started page](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started):

```
 var element = document.getElementById('test_el');
 var hammertime = Hammer(element).on('pinchin', function(event) {
     alert('hello!');
 });
```